# IE7 z-index stacking bug - how do you stack 2 absolute positioned elements correctly?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, z-index

I'm running into the IE7 z-index stacking bug, but I can't find a way to work around it. Here's a simple HTML test case:

```
<!doctype html />
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div style="position:relative; width:500px;">
    <div style="position:absolute; top:0; left:30px; width:300px; height:30px; border:1px solid #ff0000;">
        <p style="margin:0;">Menu</p>
        <ul style="position:absolute; z-index:100; list-style:none; margin:0; padding:0; background-color:#fff; border:1px solid #0000ff;">
            <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div style="position:absolute; z-index:1; top:40px; width:500px; height:75px; background-color:#ccc;">
        <p>Header</p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

In this example, you'll see that there are two absolutely positioned elements in the top level div. The first one is a menu, and the second one is a header. The menu items are not stacked correctly and show up behind the header.

[image: Screenshot]

I've read a lot of posts about the IE7 z-index bug, but I haven't found anything that helps me with this specific problem. Thanks!

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE html/>` is not a valid doctype. Use `<!DOCTYPE html>` instead, this should prevent IE from using quirksmode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a common problem with IE7 and z-index.  Here's a reference to a previous question I answered which also contains more references for further reading.

[Text overlapping items in Dropdown items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9670309/text-overlapping-items-in-dropdown-items/9670942#9670942)

Long story short, if the HEADER box and the MENU box are sibings, you need to set the z-index on those.  IE7 doesn't work if you only set the z-index on the menu items.

```
<div style="position:absolute; top:0; left:30px; width:300px; height:30px; border:1px solid #ff0000;">
```

The DIV above needs a higher z-index because it's a sibling that contains children that are doing the overlapping.

In a sense, it's required in IE7 for the parent elements to give z-index to it's children.  While not technically correct, it's easier to say or understand this way.

Here's a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JT9tw/

Answer (score 0):

Sure the li are behind the header. It is nice that your li have a higher z-index than the header. But the li a children of another stack. and that stack has a z-index of 0.
So that means your li have a Z-index off 100 in an element that has a z-index of 0 itself.
Header is another stack with z=index 1 and lies over the other div (and its children).

Answer (score 0):

Parent element position should be set to relative and the absolute positioned elements should have their display set.