# CSS Issue with Navigation Drop Down hidden on IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I am facing a problem with my navigation drop down menu hidden behind container class in IE(internet Explorer) browser but its working fine with all other browser.
I am stuck with this issue for 3 days. I tried too much to change css of my container class and my navigation class but failed :(.
I tried even display and visibility properties in my css but failed...
Please give me hint how i can fix this problem
here is my site 
http://napodfw12.wildapricot.org/
if you open it in all other browsers than IE drop down of menu bar will display but in ie it is hidden,

i am uploading screen shot of this problem too.

Comment: I would hazard a guess you're having z-index issue in IE, which is a known issue.  See if [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9670309/text-overlapping-items-in-dropdown-items/9670942#9670942) I wrote a while ago helps.

Comment: @jmbertucci i tried with adding z-index to my container div css but dod not work out.see if you can check my css with firebug and can find out solution ???

Comment: @jmbertucci i want to tell you one thing that my drop down ul have z-index value 597 but may container div css doesnot have z-indeldx value ... so let me know what should i do now ?

Comment: @jmbertucci here you see
ul.dropdown {
 position: relative;
 z-index: 597;
    padding: 0 1px 0px 31px;
 float: left;

Comment: @ben i tried with it but failed.

Answer (score 0):

IE is very annoying about z-index.  I found that creating an IE stylesheet and setting the container and nav position to relative, then adjusting the Z-index seemed to work for me.